# defining a function (somehow wrong syntax)

Tags: function, python-3.x, syntax

I wanna create a program that multiplies the users age by 50. I defined a function that allows you to do that but it still says that the "def" has the wrong syntax . please tell me what im doing wrong . thnks ( and yes im a beginner)

```
age = print(int(input("gimme age"))

def by_50(x):    
  return x * 50

print(by_50(age))
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the syntax of your function definition, but you do have a missing closing parenthesis `)` on the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're missing a finishing bracket in `print(int(input("gimme age"))`.

In addition, with `age = print(int(input("gimme age")))` you are trying to assign the return value of the function `print()` to `age`, but `print()` always returns `None`, which isn't very uesful.

Instead, you should be assigning the return value of `input()`: `age = int(input("gimme age"))`.

Full program:

```
age = int(input("gimme age"))
def by_50(x):
     return x * 50
print(by_50(age))
```

Comment: Although assigning the return value of `print()` to a variable isn't very useful, it's perfectly legal, and not what's causing the syntax error (the missing parenthesis is doing that).

Comment: Wait, I just tried but it didn't work keeping `age = print(int(input("age=")))` it returns the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\help.py", line 4, in <module>
    by_50(age)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\help.py", line 3, in by_50
    return (x*50)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'`

Comment: My apologies; I should have been more explicit. I hope you don't mind me rolling back and editing your answer to clarify things.

Comment: No problem! Happy you did :) Thank you